# I am not getting any output for the image on the button (tkinter)

Tags: tkinter

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("960x600")

canvas = Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()

imagetest = PhotoImage("//user//hisham//desktop//python//other python files//logo.png")
canvas.create_image(250, 250, image=imagetest)

button_qwer = Button(root, text="asdfasdf", image=imagetest)
button_qwer.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Output:
[image]

please help me fix this error.I was trying to put image on the button (tkinter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to the file must be passed as a keyword argument

```
PhotoImage(file=...)
           ^^^^^
```

Comment: found the error it was my python having some issues